# ggplot, geom_point color based on a variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking for a way to color points of a plot based on a variable 'var_color'.
This is an example code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(datasets)

var_color <- manufacturer

mpg %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy, color = var_color)
         ) +
  geom_point()
```

Does anyone know how can I do it?
Greetings

Comment: Try `get(var_color)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way. Use `get` to get the value of the variable `var_color`. Then change the legend title.

```
library(ggplot2)

var_color <- "manufacturer"

ggplot(mpg, mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy, color = get(var_color))) +
  geom_point() +
  guides(color = guide_legend(title = var_color))
```

[image]